# Multiple participants - multiple event registrations

Tags: civievent

I suspect I know the answer because I can't find it despite searching here & through the documentation but here goes.

We run a number of kids clubs (around 10 per week), with between 5 and 20 kids in each club. Clubs typically run for around 12 weeks each, some run more or less continuously.

I'd like to give the volunteers for each club a registration list of kids they can expect to turn up. All the clubs are free to the kids, but it's useful to know who should be there and also to track if any kids have 'dropped off the radar'.

I can register 5 kids on a single event (using smart groups & register group for event). I can do this for every club event instance, but that's very tedious.

I can't seem to register 1 kid on 5 events?

It would be awesome to be able to register 5 kids on 5 events but I suspect that's beyond scope at this point.

I know not every kid will attend every session, but it would be much easier to book them on and then cancel exceptions rather than having to book every single child-event combination by hand.

Any thoughts?

CiviCRM 4.7.17

WP 4.7.4

Comment: Nothing built in. I have made a chrome app to do it, but they are depreciated now.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the API csv Import. https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui
I could not tell you right off what fields you would need to have in your csv file to accomplish this, but I think you should be able to do it. You might have to have each child on the list 5 times to add them to 5 events (but not a big deal because you could still do it as one import). You could save some csv "templates" for each club so you do not need to recreate them every week/month.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're on Wordpress - but if the question is can a mom sign up 5 kids for 5 events on one single form then the answer is yes - you can do this if you have Drupal attached to your CiviCRM; no code required; 30min to set that up using Webform CiviCRM;

Those orgs that really want Wordpress for their front end (yourorg.org) - benefit from a Drupal/CiviCRM instance (secure.yourorg.org) - as it just lets you do way so much more with your CiviCRM giving you all the extras - while separating the Wordpress from your CiviCRM also helps to distance your CiviCRM data from potentially volnerable Wordpress plugins;